# Modify undo/redo behaviour on a textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to handle the events undo and redo myself when a user selects undo/redo from context menu or presses ctrl z in a textarea. 
How can i prevent the default behavior and add custom behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You can detect `ctrl+z` on `keyup()` with:

```
var ctrlZ = e.ctrlKey && e.which === 90
if (ctrlZ) { ... }
```

And context menu on `mousedown()` with:

```
var rightClick = e.which === 2
if (rightClick) { ... }
```

Comment: and how to prevent the default behaviour

Comment: Yo! I like bruv! no point of reposting same thing +1 innit `:)` and OP look in here as well, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Undo - also note _ I ain't sure how you are thinking of mouse click undo events.

Comment: @Tats_innit how to download the undo plugin discussed in the link you provided

Comment: yo @amit.codename13 http://code.google.com/p/jquery-values/source/browse/other/undo/jquery.undo.js?r=103 `:)` < might be >