# How to restrict "undo/redo" event on textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undo-redo

In the application, based on "keyup" and "select" events, I am setting some specific value to textarea.

For example:

The textarea has value "I am eating mangoes". When user deletes the "I" from textarea, I restrict the user from deleting the same, by assigning previous value back in the textarea.

But now, if user does "undo" action, extra "I" gets appended to the value of textarea.

It makes it look "I I restrict the user from deleting the same".

Is there any way that I can restrict undo in above case?

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: **You Can get Undo/redu Event on keyup** See [Stackoverflow Answare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501804/modify-undo-redo-behaviour-on-a-textarea-using-jquery)